# Closed subgroups in Ratner's orbit closure theorem on unipotent flows

Tags: lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $G$ be a semisimple (real or $p$-adic) Lie group and $\Gamma$ a discrete and cocompact subgroup of $G$, as in the setting of Ratner's theorems on unipotent flows (see for example here \url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratner%27s_theorems}). Write $X=\Gamma\backslash G$.

Let $U_1\subset U_2$ be two unipotent subgroups of $G$. Then Ratner's orbit closure theorem asserts that for any $x\in X$, there is a closed subgroup $H_i$ ($i=1,2$) of $G$ such that the closure $\overline{xU_i}$ is equal to $xH_i$.

My question is: what is the relation between these two closed subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$? Do we have $H_1\subset H_2$? Perhaps this is a rather trivial question, yet I failed to find an answer in the literature.

Comment: This is trivial for the $\mathbb{R}$ case. One easy argument goes like that - obviously you have inclusion of the closures, and the topological theorem of Ratner says that the closures are nice manifolds, sharing a common point (namely $\Gamma x$), hence you have an inclusion on the level of the tangent spaces (which gives rise to the Lie algebras). Now $H_{i}$ are also connected (they are groups of type $R$), hence the inclusion of the Lie algebras is (more than) enough to conclude the inclusion of the groups....

Comment: @Asaf : Thanks a lot for your nice argument. I guess this argument carries over to the $p$-adic case, using the correspondence between Lie subgroups and Lie subalgebras? By the way, can you give some references for the fact that $H_i$ are connected, or of type $R$, in the real case?

Comment: One should be a tiny bit careful in the $p$-adic case, but I suspect it should work as everything is analytic. The fact about $H_{i}$'s being connected is probably already in Ratner's Acta paper. I guess the rest is in Margulis-Tomanov (where they prove the $p$-adic versions) or in Dani-Margulis and the subsequent linearization papers (Mozes-Shah?). The best current source is the effective linearization paper of Lindenstrauss et al.

Comment: Connectedness is Theorem 6.1.2 in Ratner's Acta paper...